# problem with socks in proxychains

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy, socks

I'm trying to connect to a socks server using `proxychains`.
My `ProxyList` part of `proxychains.conf` is:

```
socks5   ip1.sockssrv.org      1080    MYUSER   MYPASS
```

When I try to use it; for example using this command:

```
proxychains wget -qO- ifconfig.me/ip
```

I'm getting this:

```
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
|DNS-request| ifconfig.me 
|DNS-response|: ifconfig.me is not exist
```

By disabling `proxy_dns`; it only prints version and doesn't connect at all:

```
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
```

Note:  The command works without `proxychains` and the socks server is up and works with `proxifier` (Windows application).

What is the problem?

Thanks